# Return specific value based on string in text

Tags: excel, if-statement, search

I have one Excel file where every year has a specific number against it. I want to automate the process and create a column which will return the stored value based on the year mentioned in string.

```
Salefile                       Fixed value for year
CS Tota 2016 batch20             23  
CS 1040 (2017)                   26  
CS 1041 (2018)                   30  
CS 1040 (2019)                   34
```

What I need is
Under 'salefile' column each week I am adding new file name, format of the filename (CS file number yyyy). When a new file name is added the value corresponding to the year in filename will come up. Ex: If my next 'Salefile' is cs 1044 (2018), 30 should generate under 'fixed value

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you upload one screenshot of your data?

Answer (score 0):

1] Create a lookup Table in `E4:F8`

In Output, "Criteria" `B5:B8`, enter : `2017,2019,2016 and 2018`

In "Result" `C5`, enter formula and copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(1,-FIND(B5,$E$5:$E$8),$F$5:$F$8)
```

[image]

Edit :

Here is another set up

2] Create a Lookup Table in `E4:F8`

In "Salefile" column B enter the criteria

In "Fixed value" (Result) `C5`, formula copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/ISNUMBER(FIND($E$5:$E$8,B5)),$F$5:$F$8)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help. The problem is little different . Under 'salefile' column each  week I am adding new file name, When a new file name is added the value corresponding to the year in filename will come up. Ex: If my next 'Salefile' is cs 1044 (2018), 30 should generate under 'fixed value'

Comment: @Sumaiya Khatun, Please see new edited post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use

`=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("*"&E1&"*",$A:$A,0),2)),"No match")`

`MATCH("*"&E1&"*",$A:$A,0)`

- Provide the row where the value of E1 found.
- `$A:$A` refer to column A (Fix range using $ sign)
- `0` used for taking exact match

`ADDRESS(MATCH("*"&E1&"*",$A:$A,0),2)`

- The `MATCH function` used to provide the row we need
- `2` targeting column B

`INDIRECT()`

- Used to get the value of the specific row - column

`=IFERROR()`

- In case the value of E1 does not match, "No match" warning will appears

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help. The problem is little different . Under 'salefile' column each week I am adding new file name, When a new file name is added the value corresponding to the year in filename will come up. Ex: If my next 'Salefile' is cs 1044 (2018), 30 should generate under 'fixed value